# Run South Migration in Background

Tags: python, linux, django-south

I have a Huge table `A` and it want to add `db_index` plus want to add a new field in `A`.

It takes me alot of time run the migration.
I want to ask if I can run the migration in background?

Like

`nohup python manage.py migrate my_app &`

But I am not getting any output in the `nohup.out` file. I was wondering if my command is actually running, if so how much if have progressed?

### Tried

```
pgrep -lf python
```

Any Suggestions? Why Am I not getting outputs in file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to run tasks in background and do not loose data with internet disconnect then Try using `Screen` module on `linux`

`sudo apt-get install screen`

Find the documentation [here.](http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/)